# Flutter - TextOverflow.ellipsis has ellipsis centred

Tags: flutter

[image]

TextOverflow.ellipsis is not putting the ellipsis on the text baseline. I am assuming its because it does not know where the baseline is, especially since I have specified the max lines to be 1.

I have found packages that seem to be able to fix the issue [for example this](https://pub.dev/packages/ellipsis_overflow_text) but I don't want to use a package for something that should be a simple fix.

```
 Row(
  children: [
    const Column(
      children: [
        // other widgets here
      ],
    ),
    const SizedBox(width: 16),
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            title,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            softWrap: true,
            maxLines: 1,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    // other widgets after
  ],
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? I tried this code and the ellipsis is aligned to the baseline, you can try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=cf8b4de72ede07895b4564608fa47de4)

Comment: @DhafinRayhan Hi, I have just edited the question and provided a screenshot.

Comment: As you can see in the DartPad link that I gave, the ellipsis is aligned with the baseline. It seems like you're using a custom font that caused the issue

Comment: Copy/pasted your code in the Dart Pad. It is running as expected like @DhafinRayhan said. Check if the alignment of the Parent Widgets above this widget isn't causing this issue.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan Yeah it was the custom font causing the issue. Removing custom font fixed it. I didn't even consider that this was the issue thank you.